# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError keeps occurring, what is a better way to store a million strings and their counts?

Tags: java, memory, hashmap, storage

I am currently trying to store a million strings and their counts into a hashmap.
However, I keep running out of memory. Is there a better way to do this such that I can also keep its count for another task later?

The input is: 
al = new String[]{"A", "C", "G", "T", "AC", "AG", "AT", "CG", "CT", "GT", "ACGT"};

```
public static Map < String, Integer > combinations(String[] al) {

    HashMap < String, Integer > consData = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
    String nc;
    for (String s: al) {
      for (String k: al) {
        for (String l: al) {
          for (String m: al) {
            for (String n: al) {
              for (String o: al) {
                nc = s + "|" + k + "|" + l + "|" + m + "|" + n + "|" + o;
                consData.put(nc, 0);
                System.out.println(nc);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: give the jvm more memory. (by the way you only put `0` in there, which is not theyr count?)

Comment: For such amount of data, increase your memory RAM to have enough space to store all that (not sure how many GBs you will need) or use a database instead.

Comment: if increasing memory does not work consider to use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: A million of anything is not that much for a computer.  One million is about 4 megabytes just for the pointers, plus the data, which shouldn't be that much on a machine that should have many gigabytes available.  However Java `String` is not very efficient or compact, so consider a different data formant that compresses your data better.  Java has an overhead of about 20 bytes per string, which isn't great.

Comment: @markspace consider before compressing data if it is really necessary to store all the data (see my answer on sparse matrix). Millions of data is not too much if you need them, if not you only loose a lot of space and time saving them.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems that you need to store millions of string as keys for a Map.

I see that you put a number on the map, initially 0.

How often this value will change from 0? If this value is not often different from zero you have a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

In this situation you can decide to store a data in the map only if its value is different from zero and using a method like the following to get the value of a generic string:

```
public int getValue(String key) {
    Integer value = consData.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return value;
}
```

If the value is a counter of existing elements with that key the add method could be the following:

```
public int addKey(String key) {
    Integer counter = consData.get(key);
    if (counter == null) {
        counter = 0;
    } 
    counter = counter + 1;
    consData.put(key, counter);        
}
```

This solution is often used when you have millions of possible values, but only few of them are *valid*

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices:

Increase the memory you give the process when it starts.

Use a more memory efficient storage method( a trie *might* work but might have too much overhead).

Use a database and store the data there.

Something like an embedded Derby database for example means you can run the database inside your program but still let it handle all the indexes, storing to disk, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to reduce memory usage. One way is to only put entries in the map if the value is greater than zero.

Another way is to use packed ints rather than string keys. This way the strings can be used to put and get from the map, but the strings do not need to be retained after the `put` or `get` calls.

If you really do need a count for every possible combination, you could use an `int[]` rather than a `HashMap` to avoid creating millions of `Map.Entry` objects.

Here is one possible solution putting these ideas together. You could improve it further by replacing `al` with an enum.

```
public class Main {

    private static final int PATTERN_LENGTH = 6;

    private static final String[] al = {"A", "C", "G", "T", "AC", "AG", "AT", "CG", "CT", "GT", "ACGT"};

    private static final Map<String, Integer> indices = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < al.length; i++)
            indices.put(al[i], i);
    }

    private static int pack(String... p) {
        if (p.length != PATTERN_LENGTH)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < PATTERN_LENGTH; i++)
            temp |= indices.get(p[i]) << i * 4;
        return temp;
    }

    private static int pack2(String withDelimeters) {
        return pack(withDelimeters.split("\\|"));
    }

    // Not actually used, but it's good to know the reverse of pack.
    private static String[] unpack(int a) {
        String[] temp = new String[PATTERN_LENGTH];
        for (int i = 0; i < PATTERN_LENGTH; i++)
            temp[i] = al[(a >>> (i * 4)) & 0xF];
        return temp;
    }

    // This array has length 2^24 = 16777216, whereas technically an array
    // of length only 11^6 = 1771561 (10 times smaller) is required. You would 
    // need to come up with a cleverer way of making the packed ints, such    
    // as using a base-11 encoding, rather than using 4 bits for each symbol.
    static final int[] counts = new int[1 << 24];

    private static void put(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4, String p5, String p6, int count) {
        counts[pack(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6)] = count;
    }

    private static void put(String s, int count) {
        counts[pack2(s)] = count;
    }

    private static int get(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4, String p5, String p6) {
        return counts[pack(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6)];
    }

    private static int get(String s) {
        return counts[pack2(s)];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Both put and get accept both the comma separated, or | separated versions. 
        put("AC", "A", "C", "G", "T", "ACGT", 10);
        System.out.println(get("AC|A|C|G|T|ACGT"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which is a data structure that efficiently uses memory with fairly efficient insertion and query. Put count in the terminal node.